# MenuBar non selectable sub titles

Tags: gwt, title, menubar, selectable

I have a horizontal menu bar with a child vertical drop-down menu bar.
I would like it so that the child vertical menu bar contains something like the following:

Title text 1

Separator 1

Option 1.1

Option 1.2

Title text 2

Separator 2

Option 2.1

Option 2.2

Is there a way to add non-selectable text into a MenuBar as I don't want the user able to select the "Title text" elements?

Answer (score 1):

`myTitleMenuItem.`[`setEnabled`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuItem.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29)`(false)` ?

Answer (score 0):

As T Broyer answered u can do setEnabled(false). You will get a disabled style for the item which would not look good.

And coming to User experience, User usually expects each item in the Menu Bar to perform some action. When he sees some item with text and not performing any action on clicking, he gets a impression like 'App is not working or not responding'.

So, its always better to create a Menu Item 'Title Text' and also create a Menu Bar with required items and set this menu bar as a child or SubMenu of Title Text item.

So, whenever user hovers or clicks on the 'Title Text item' sub menu will be shown.